# passing state in react with useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I'm new to react and trying to learn by building this simple app. I want to expose data from parent app in a child component but my result in the component appears to be empty.
what should I do to get the result to appear and re-render in the child component?

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";
    import Main from "./Main";
    import Response from "./response"
    const ENDPOINT = "http://127.0.0.1:4001";
    
    
    function App() {
      const [response, setResponse] = useState([]);
    
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const socket = socketIOClient(ENDPOINT);
        socket.on("tick", (data) => {
          setResponse(data);
        });
      }, []);
    
    
    
      console.log(response);
    
    
      return (
        <>
          <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
            <Main
             responseCurrency = {response.map(memb => <div>{memb.currencyPairName}</div>)}
             dataObject = {response}
            />
          </div>
        </>
    
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

```
   import './Main.css';
   
   function Main(props) {
   
     const [result, setResult] = React.useState(props.dataObject);
   
     React.useEffect(() => {
       console.log(result)
       setResult(result);
     }, [result]);
   
     return <div className="container">
     {result[0]}
     <div id="palceholder1" className="placeholder">hello</div>
     <div id="palceholder2" className="placeholder"></div>
     <div id="palceholder3" className="placeholder"></div>
     </div>;
   }
   
   
   export default Main;
```

I am a beginner in ReactJS, so I'm lost at the moment.
Hope someone could shed a light..
Thanks in advance

Gali

Answer (score 1):

```
function Main(props) {
   
     const [result, setResult] = React.useState(props.dataObject);
```

The problem is that you're copying props into state. The above line of code says to create a new state for Main, who's **initial** value is props.dataObject. When props.dataObject changes later, nothing will happen to this state.

Instead, you should use the prop directly:

```
function Main(props) {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      {props.dataObject[0]}
      <div id="palceholder1" className="placeholder">
        hello
      </div>
      <div id="palceholder2" className="placeholder"></div>
      <div id="palceholder3" className="placeholder"></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: tried it and got this Error: "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {currencyPairName, prices}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead." which is weird because my data is an array of 3 Objects.. what am I missing?

Comment: `my data is an array of 3 Objects` From that it follows that element 0 of the array is an object. So `{props.dataObject[0]}` is trying to put an object on the page, which isn't supported. Is there some property inside the object that you want to put on the page?

Comment: it doesn't work. I get this "TypeError: Cannot read property 'currencyPairName' of undefined", when I try to pass the object and extract the value in the component. I think it's a socket thing and I need to create a new obj and pass it to the update func so React can..react. with that, it's still not working for me :(